# ionic2 currency formatting broken on device

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

Ionic2 framework allows to format currency like `{{finalPremium | currency : 'eur' : true :'.2-2' }}`.

However, this only seems to work int the browser. When launched on a device (iPhone) I cannot see any errors in the logs but the page displaying the formatted currency will not show.

## edit

On a android device it works just fine.

Comment: I thought I'd let you know I have the same behaviour on a page that uses the currency filter, although i cannot confirm if this is the culprit or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currency pipe uses a web API that is not available across all browsers, so it should be fixed by you adding a polyfill or by the developer of that pipe (angular 2).

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html

> The Date and Currency pipes need the ECMAScript Internationalization
>   API. Safari and other older browsers don't support it. We can add
>   support with a polyfill.

You can use [Intl.js polyfill](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js).